# Minecraft Bedrock Player File Locations

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I was sent the save file for a realm and uploaded it as my own realm. I logged in but I spawned with the original owner's gear and in their location. How could I change my player data to what it was before I became the owner and where would it be located? I see a lot of .ldb files in the save that I think are the player saves but I'm not sure since when I open it, it's a jumbled mess of code.

Comment: look into [universalminecrafteditor](https://www.universalminecrafteditor.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Bedrock edition uses a format know as leveldb. It was made by Google, although mojang maintains their own version for the game:

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bedrock_Edition_level_format

Player inventories are stored with the ldb files (the db folder essentially consists of one database). Each player inventory is stored under the key "player_ID" where id is the integer id of the player. There is also a special key "~local_player" which represents the local player's inventory (game host or realm owner). This inventory takes precedence over any remote inventory for the same player. This would be the inventory you'd need to either edit out or transfer using a level editor such as Mctool chest or universal minecraft editor.