# How do I obtain the coordinates of another player using only the game files?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have a survival realm with no cheats, and I would like to know the location of a specific player. I went on to export the world, then changed the file extension to `.zip`. I looked in the `level.dat` and `level.dat_old` files and could not find any data about player location, so I thought it might be in the `db` folder. I looked at all the files except the files with the `.ldb` extension, as I couldn't seem to get any readable information from `.ldb` files. Which file contains the player coordinates and how do I read the file?

**Note:** `.ldb` files appear to be a temporary file made by Microsoft access to keep track of who is editing a database. I don’t get why they are in the Minecraft data files.

**Update:** I converted the world to a Java Edition world and opened it using the NBT Explorer. I'm not sure which folder to look in.

Comment: I think you do need to look at the .ldb files - see [Minecraft Bedrock Player File Locations](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/381450/minecraft-bedrock-player-file-locations), which this is almost but not quite a duplicate of.